# Meteor.users additional fields

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoose

How can I add new field to the current logged in user in document using 'Meteor.user()'?

NOTE: I am using [meteoris](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=meteoris) packages to create and manage my users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
 Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() },{ $set: { 'propertyHere': valueOfPropertyHere } });
```

Note: If you are updating the user from the client you need to make sure you have the correct permissions, also the `Meteor.userId()` would work.

If you are doing it from the server then change the `Meteor.userId()` to `this.userId` .. tested on Meteor 1.6